# Building Android keyboard that uses the Coptic Unicode block

Tags: android, unicode

I am building a keyboard that uses the Coptic block with Unicode range 2C80 to 2CFF. I am sure that Android support this range of Unicode characters: correct me if I am wrong. However, all characters appear as a crossed square.

Should I import anything in my code to get these characters supported?

Answer (score 0):

Characters appearing as squares are usually a font problem. Install a font like Code 2000, and make sure you select that in your code.

Comment: I want this keyboard to work on all browsers , android and other devices so I use Unicode to be supported on all devices without install any thing beside the keyboard.

If there is no other way to get it works directly so importing this font in the app will work for me.